# Is deluxetable compatible with the endfloat package?

Tags: endfloat, aastex

For my thesis, I am making a table using `deluxetable` and the `aastex` class but need all my tables and figures to go at the end of the document. The `endfloat` package seemed to be perfect for this, but for some reason the `deluxetable` table will not move to the end of the document. Figures and normal tables will just fine, but not `deluxetabe`s. Is `deluxetable` not compatible with `endfloat`?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\begin{document}


\begin{deluxetable}{ll}
\tablecolumns{2} 
\tablewidth{0pt} 
\tablecaption{Sample Table}
\tablehead{\colhead{Column 1}   &
           \colhead{Column 2} 
           }
\startdata
a & b \\
c & d \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also have a look, if `\documentclass{article}` results in the same problem. It is always easier for us to test issues on standard classes. Personally, I do not know and have `aastex`

Comment: The deluxetable environment is built into `aastex` and I'm not sure if it's possible to download it separately for use in the normal article class. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endfloat` does not know the environment `deluxetable` and therefore has no idea of how to handle it. I just defined `deluxteable` to be treated as a `table`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{deluxetable}{table}

\begin{document}    
\begin{deluxetable}{ll}
    \tablecolumns{2} 
    \tablewidth{0pt} 
    \tablecaption{Sample Table}
    \tablehead{\colhead{Column 1}   &
        \colhead{Column 2} 
    }
    \startdata
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \enddata
\end{deluxetable}   
\end{document}
```

> This tells the endfloat package that [...] should be treated as table,
>   at least from endfloat ’s point of view. If you keep your fingers
>   crossed this may actually work. - `endloat` [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) p. 8

Comment: @Guest122 You are welcome.